# How to combined the itemList to single line?

Tags: c#, list, oop, join

I want my genre to join together instead print in diff line.
How do i join my genre join like "Action, Adventure" instead print into two diff line?
My output print in two different line.
Sorry for format and bad english.

My code:

```
    static void initMovies(List<Movie> mList)
    {
        Movie m;

        
        m = new Movie("The Great Wall", 103, "NC16", new DateTime(2016,12,29),new List<string> { "Action", "Adventure" });
        mList.Add(m);


        m = new Movie("Rogue One: A Star Wars Story", 134, "PG13", new DateTime(2016,12,15),new List<string> { "Action","Adventure"});
        mList.Add(m);


        m = new Movie("Office Christmas Party", 106, "M18", new DateTime(2017,01,15),new List<string> { "Comedy" });
        mList.Add(m);

        m = new Movie("Power Rangers", 120, "G",new DateTime(2017,1,31),new List<string>{ "Fantasy","Thriller"});
        mList.Add(m);
    }
  

 
static void displayMovie(List<Movie> mList)
{ 
    Movie m;
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-30} {2,-10} {3,-20} {4,-20} {5,-10}","No","Title","Duration","Genre","Classification","Opening Date");
    var gList = new List<List<string>>();
    for(int i = 0; i<mList.Count;i++)
    {
        m = mList[i];
        foreach (string value in m.GetGenreList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-30} {2,-10} {3,-20} {4,-20} {5,-10}", i + 1, m.Title, m.Duration, value, m.Classification, m.openingDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:
[image: image1]

My Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: It's considered very rude here to post an image instead of text for sample data or outputs.

Comment: what tgt ? can you please add text of your data

Comment: Do share the sample data as well so we can easily test it out. :)

Comment: Is this much better?

Comment: How bout the list of movie in text?

Comment: whats the criteria for joining? all other columns must be the same or if some of them be equal is enough?

Comment: Please show your movie class, specifically what type of collection you are using for Genre. But odds are you can flatten out the List of Genre by using `.SelectMany(x =>x)`

Comment: @prtdomingo i have update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `string.join` to join elements you get from GetGenreList() method and omit the inner `foreach` loop as following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mList.Count; i++)
{
    m = mList[i];
    //foreach (string value in m.GetGenreList())
    //{
        string all_genres = string.Join(",", m.GetGenreList()); //get all genres as a comma seperated in single string
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-30} {2,-10} {3,-20} {4,-20} {5,-10}", i + 1, m.Title, m.Duration, all_genres, m.Classification, m.openingDate);
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just remove the inner foreach and use `string.Join` here.

Here's an example:

```
static void displayMovie(List<Movie> mList)
{ 
    Movie m;
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-30} {2,-10} {3,-20} {4,-20} {5,-10}","No","Title","Duration","Genre","Classification","Opening Date");
    var gList = new List<List<string>>();
    for(int i = 0; i<mList.Count;i++)
    {
        m = mList[i];
            string genres = string.Join(", ", m.GetGenreList().ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-30} {2,-10} {3,-20} {4,-20} {5,-10}", i + 1, m.Title, m.Duration, genres, m.Classification, m.openingDate);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Hope it helps!